# How to patch array data of k8s yaml file on condition using yq?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, yq

I have a project that need to update cloneset yaml

YAML document something like:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps.kruise.io/v1alpha1
kind: CloneSet
metadata:
  generation: 1
  ...
spec:
  ...
  ...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: data1
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 60G
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: data2
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 60G
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
```

I want to patch volumeClaimTemplates based on metadata.name

If name is not specified, storages for **all volumeClaimTemplates** are updated, and if name is specified and is matched, storages for a specific name are updated, if name is specified, but name  don't match, return error

```sh
matchVolumeTemplateName=${1-all}
storage="$2"
if [[ ${matchVolumeTemplateName} == "all" ]]; then
  ./bin/yq e -i ".spec.volumeClaimTemplates[].spec.resources.requests.storage = \"${storage}\"" "cloneset_modifystorage.yml"
else
  ./bin/yq e -i ".spec.volumeClaimTemplates[] | select(.metadata.name == "\"${matchVolumeTemplateName}\"").spec.resources.requests.storage |= \"${storage}\"" "cloneset_modifystorage.yml"
fi
```

However, with the above code, **only part of the YAML data** will be output if `a match is found` for the specified name, and the file will be **empty** if name don't match, for example `matchVolumeTemplateName=data3`

```yaml
# cloneset_modifystorage.yml
# matchVolumeTemplateName = data1   storage = 90G

# Other data of K8S YAML is lost
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: data1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 90G
```

As a result, other data information about K8S is **missing**, and an empty file is printed **instead of an error** when a name match fails.

I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Did provided answer help you?

Comment: I have noticed the answer has been deleted - so I suggest starting from beggining. Could you provide version of Kubernetes that you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing brackets - so it's first filtering the yaml and then updating (instead of updating a specific portion of the yaml):

```sh
./bin/yq e -i "(.spec.volumeClaimTemplates[] | select(.metadata.name == "\"${matchVolumeTemplateName}\"").spec.resources.requests.storage) |= \"${storage}\"" "cloneset_modifystorage.yml"
```

Disclosure: I wrote yq

Comment: That's really a handy tool. Is there a method that returns an error when a match fails, as in the example matchVolumeTemplateName=data3

Comment: Yep, there's a '-e' flag for that

Comment: -e seems to be for key only. I tested the following method but did not get an error. `export matchVolumeTemplateName=data3&&export storage=50G&&./bin/yq e -e "(.spec.volumeClaimTemplates[] | select(.metadata.name == "\"${matchVolumeTemplateName}\"").spec.resources.requests.storage) |= \"${storage}\"" "ez-auth-token.yml"`. It's just unmodified content